# Why my Watermark does not show in center in java?

Tags: java, image-processing, bufferedimage

I went through many tutorials and finally got my **image Watermarked with a logo and text together** but the problem is that my text is not shown *horizontally centered* to the image but the text starts from the center itself.

Here is my code

```
BufferedImage waterMark = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/haams/MyLogo.png"));
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File(MyImage.getAbsolutePath()));
Graphics2D g = image.createGraphics();
try 
{
   g.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.5f));// 50% transp
   g.drawImage(waterMark, image.getWidth() - waterMark.getWidth(), image.getHeight() - waterMark.getHeight(), null);// draw in lower right corner

   FontMetrics fontMetrics = g.getFontMetrics();
   Rectangle2D rect = fontMetrics.getStringBounds("Testing WaterMark", g);

   g.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 30));
   g.drawString("Testing WaterMark",(image.getWidth() - (int) rect.getWidth()) / 2, (image.getHeight() - (int) rect.getHeight()) / 2);
   //Above line should place my String in center but the text starts from center
}
finally 
{
   g.dispose();
}
ImageIO.write(image, FileName.substring(FileName.lastIndexOf('.')+1),  new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\"+FileName));
```

In my output `MyLogo` is placed correctly where I want it to be but the `Text` starts from Center instead of being in Center.

I don't have 10 points to upload an image so I would try my best to illustrate what I mean

My Image and text inside it

```
 -----------------------------------
 |                                  |
 |                                  |
 |                                  |
 |                                  |
 |                                  |
 |                Test WaterMark    |
 |                                  |
 |                                  |
 |                                  |
 |                                  |
 |                                  |
 -----------------------------------
```

You can see that the text starts from center instead of being in center. What's wrong in my code?

Comment: What happens if you set your font on the graphics before you get the string bounds? I'm thinking you're doing the calculation for the position with a different font

Comment: @ToonBorgers same thing :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion the problem could be, that you do

```
FontMetrics fontMetrics = g.getFontMetrics();
```

before you set the font you want to use

```
g.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 30));
```

Make sure to set the font first and get the metrics after setting a font.

Comment: I will accept your answer as soon as it happens with 10 minutes.